# Simplify formula with several SUBSTITUTE for the same final value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use this formula that several values ​​must be substituted for the same value `&&&&&`, I would like to know if there is a way to simplify it so it doesn't get too big and so repetitive

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,"2020","&&&&&"),"20202021","&&&&&"),"2021","&&&&&"),"20212022","&&&&&"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one method, for example, how about using `REGEXREPLACE` as follows?

#### Modified formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"2020|20202021|2021|20212022","&&&&&"))
```

#### Reference:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)